# How to add a tag on a deleted file in CVS?

Tags: datagrid, tags, branch, cvs

I need to create a branch from the state of the `HEAD` several days ago, for which I would like to add a tag on all files in a module. Trouble is that a few files were removed using `cvs` remove between that day and now. When I tried to do "`cvs rtag`" using `-D` option, I don't see the tag on the deleted files although the deleted files existed then in the `cvs`.

Is there a straightforward way to branch from a specific date with all the files that existed then?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `cvs (r)tag` does not allow mixing the `-D` and `-r` options. But `cvs update` does, so you can update your working copy to the date and branch you want and then `cvs tag` your working copy.